# How to change social network icons colors in fixed menu?

Tags: css, colors

I have problem with making colors in small fixed manu , when someone scroll down. In first main menu (white text, with black backgorund, social icons is ok), but in small fixed menu, when someone scroll down, social network is not shown, if used is not close with arrow on it. How to make social network icons to be showed in black color in white fixed menu? I tryed adding this CSS:

```
[class^="fa-"],
[class*=" fa-"] {
color:#000;
}
```

but this CSS makes social networks in main black menu black, and not visible. How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance. Site [URL](http://deil.cz/)

Comment: Can you show a working example please?

Comment: And your html code is...?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i included link in first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll down, javascript is triggering a class 'mini' in your menu.
If you want to show black icons only when the 'mini' menu is active you could add to your css :

```
.mini [class^="fa-"],
.mini [class*=" fa-"] {
       color:#000;
   }
}
```

So classes that start with "fa-" ([class^="fa-"]) and classes that contain " fa-" ([class*=" fa-"]) would only be affected if one of their parent has a class 'mini'

Comment: Thanks @kevin-amiranoff